# VBA Excel bulk data loop for few columns at once

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon,

I have a set of working code, which works as a loop between values i = 0-90 step 0.25. It gives 360 combinations exactly.

I used to do this loop separately column by column. It takes time and I must repeat the process exactly 9 times.

[image]

So, red bounded is the column first, which I am currently working on. The blue bounds apply to different columns.
The value comes from a completely different worksheet. 
The output is stored in a complete worksheet too (as below).
[image]

My working codes look as follows:

```
 Sub calc4()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("9")
.UsedRange.clear
.Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("b1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 90 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i * (-1)
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("B371").Value
    End With
Next I
End With
End Sub

Sub calc3()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("9")
.UsedRange.clear
'.Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("c1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 90 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("D371").Value
    End With
Next I
End With
End Sub


Sub calc2()
Dim i As Single
  With Worksheets("9")
   .UsedRange.clear
  ' .Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("d1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 90 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("F371").Value
    End With
  Next I
 End With
End Sub


 Sub calc1()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("9")
.UsedRange.clear
.Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("e1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 90 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("H371").Value
    End With
Next I
End With
End Sub

Sub calc085()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("9")
.UsedRange.clear
.Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("f1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 490 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("I371").Value
    End With
  Next I
End With
End Sub

 Sub calc06()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("9")
.UsedRange.clear
.Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("g1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 45 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("L371").Value
    End With
   Next I
End With
End Sub

Sub calc17()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("9")
.UsedRange.clear
.Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("h1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 90 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("N371").Value
    End With
Next I
End With
End Sub

Sub calc276a()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("9")
.UsedRange.clear
.Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("i1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 90 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("P371").Value
    End With
Next I
End With
End Sub

Sub calc38a()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("9")
.UsedRange.clear
.Range("a1").Value = "Input"
.Range("j1").Value = "Output"
For i = 0 To 90 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range("R371").Value
    End With
Next I
End With
End Sub
```

basically it's every 2 columns as you can see. The exception is column H and I, next to each other. In this event even split this loop into 2 separate will help me a lot. Is it possible?

Comment: You will want to iterate rows 1-90 (0-90 is 91 iterations) *once*, regardless of how many columns you have to work with. The macro is a sheet traversal; coding it as such would slash its execution time big time - or do you need 9 separate outputs? If not, then why does every output procedure begin with clearing the used range of the output sheet?

Comment: Also you're working out where to write next at each iteration; tracking which row you're at instead, would eliminate that worksheet operation and speed things up too.

Comment: Your code is not matching up with your output worksheet "9". In each of your `calc` routines, you are simply assigning the loop variable `i` to column A and the *exact same value from `Worksheets("4.MINUTES").Range(x371).Value`. How is the value is column B changing? Plus, as you're looping, you are updating the loop value to a single cell on "1_GENERAL" worksheet. It's unclear how your VBA logic works to produce the output shown.

Comment: OK let me do the explanation:
I am doing these calculations for 360 records exactly. They refer to latitude 0-90 divided by 4, hence step 0.25. The step value comes from the 1_GENERAL sheet, which links values in 4.MINUTES. This is why the loop is going this way. As the value in 1_GENERAL changes, all the calculations change in 4.MINUTES sheet bringing the different summary calculated in .Range(x371).Value. Because each loop is related to a separate columns in 4.MINUTES (B371, D371, F371, etc), I need 9 separate outputs in Sheet "9" columns B-J.